# linux - running a process and tailing a file simultaneously

Tags: bash, shell, tail

I want a run a long task on a remote machine (with python fabric using ssh).
It logs to a file on the remote machine.
What I want to do is to run that script and tail (actively display) the log file content until the script execution ends.
The problem with

```
python test.py & tail -f /tmp/out
```

is that it does not terminate when test.py exits.
Is there a simple linux trick I can use to do this or do I have to make a sophisticated script to continuously check the termination of the first process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply start the `tail` in background and the python process in foreground. When the python process finishes you can kill the `tail`, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /tmp/out # Make sure that the file exists
tail -f /tmp/out &
pid=$!
python test.py
kill "$pid"
```